# I'll be at my office by 7 p.m. I'll be at my office until 7 p.m

Tags: time

My question is: 
Does sentence "I'll be at my office by 7 p.m." means that I will not be phisical non-stop at office until 7 pm?
Does sentence "I'll be at my office until 7 p.m." means that I will be phisical non-stop at office until 7 pm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"By 7 p.m." means that you'll arrive at the office at some point before 7 p.m., so that at 7 p.m. you'll certainly be there - this is usually intended as a promise that you won't be late to arrive. It doesn't mean you won't be there earlier.

"Until 7 p.m." means that you won't leave the office before 7 p.m.

Also, *at the office* (as opposed to *in the office*) doesn't necessarily mean you have to be physically stuck in the room - if you take a bathroom break, for example, or go outside for a smoke you can still say you're at the office even if you're not physically in it.